# delete row from db using php/mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please take a look at the loop:

```
    $category = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM category');
    $divcounter = 0;
    while($row = $category->fetch_assoc()) {
        print '<div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">';
        print '<h4><a href="#tvb'.$row["id"].'" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="tvb'.$row["id"].'" class="label label-success full-width"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> '.$row["catname"].'</a></h4>';
        print '<div id="tvb'.$row["id"].'">';
        $link = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE category='{$row["id"]}'");
        while($row = $link->fetch_assoc()) {
            print '<li><a href="'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["name"].'</a>&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>';
        }
        $link->free();
        print '</div>';
        print '</div>';
        $divcounter++;
        !($divcounter % 2) ? print '<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>' : '';
        !($divcounter % 4) ? print '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>' : '';
        !($divcounter % 6) ? print '<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>' : '';
    }
```

Please advise how do I create a button that sit next to the li to delete that current listed row from db? Thanks

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

This is the content of delete.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['catid']) and is_numeric($_POST['catid']))
        $id=$_POST['catid'];
        $query = "DELETE FROM category WHERE id=(?)";
        $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('i', $id);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        while($row = $link->fetch_assoc()) {
        print '<li><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" onclick="alert(\'Are you sure you want to delete this record?\')">delete</a><a href="'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["name"].'</a>&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>';
    }
```